# Create a mysql table with ajax and html in cordova app

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, cordova

I'm working on an app with cordova and i would like to craete a page where people can create and join different rooms (in which people can do different actions). But i tried different tutorials and surfed a lot the internet trying to understand how to create mySQL tables with html and ajax requests to a php file, but nothing seems to work... Can you guys help me understand how to create a table from a html page with ajax? (sorry for my english, i'm italian!)

here's a test with a simple registration form that doesn't seems to work

index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

    <form class="" name="form">
      username: <input type="text" id="username" type="text"> <br/>
      email: <input type="text" id="email" type="text"> <br/>
      full name: <input type="text" id="fullname" type="text"> <br/>
      password: <input type="password" id="password" type="text"> <br/>

      <input type="button" onclick="ajaxFunction()" value="send">

    </form>

    <div id="ajaxDiv">YOUR RESULT WILL BE SHOWN HERE</div>

</body>
```

script.js

```
function ajaxFunction(){

  var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
      var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById("ajaxDiv");
      ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
  }

  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var fullname = document.getElementById("fullname").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  var queryString = "?name=" + username;
  queryString += "&email=" + email + "&fullname=" + fullname + "&password=" + password;
  console.log(queryString);
  ajaxRequest.open("GET","fetchdata.php" + queryString, true);
  ajaxRequest.send(null);

}
```

and my php file:

```
    <?php

  $dbhost = "localhost";
  $dbuser = "root";
  $dbpassword = "root";
  $db = "utopy";

  $username = $_GET["username"];
  $email = $_GET["email"];
  $fullname = $_GET["fullname"];
  $password = $_GET["password"];

  $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$db);
  if(!$conn){
    die("Connection Failed: " .mysqli_connect_error());
  }

  $sql = "INSERT INTO haus (username, password, full_name, email) VALUES (?s,?s,?s,?s)",$username,$email,$fullname,$password);
  if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
    echo "NEW RECORD CREATED";
  } else {
    echo "ERROR: " .$sql. "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
  }

  mysqli_close($conn);

 ?>
```

Comment: Devi , mettere un po di codice nella tua domanda , se no la gente ti inzia sotto votare , devi far vedere quello che hai tentato di fare fin'ora

Comment: hai ragione, aggiornato la domanda con gli esempi... sapresti aiutarmi ?

Comment: certamente , adesso leggo il codice e ti faccio sapere

Comment: Is it that you get an error or nothing happens?

Comment: No it will not work , as his code is not correct

Comment: @utopy ti ho risposto con il codice php da cambiare , usa quel codice

Answer (score 0):

Your php code is completely messed up , the way you are trying to insert the query , it will not work like that.

First problem is `$dbpass` should be `$dbpassword` and the next problem is you are trying to use the prepare function which does not even exist.

What you have to do is escape the data you are recieving from the users  by using `mysqli_real_escape_string` and then insert it , replace your whole php code with the below one

(cancella il tuo codice e usa quello sotto ):

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpassword = "root";
$db = "test";

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET["username"]);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET["email"]);
$fullname = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET["fullname"]);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET["password"]);

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpassword,$db);
if(!$conn){
die("Connection Failed: " .mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO haus (username, password, full_name, email) VALUES ('$username','$email','$fullname','$password')";
if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
echo "NEW RECORD CREATED";
} else {
echo "ERROR: " .$sql. "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

if you want to make cross domain request then you have to use the below javascript code

```
function ajaxFunction(){
  var ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest({mozSystem: true});
  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4) {
      var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById("ajaxDiv");
      ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
  }

  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var fullname = document.getElementById("fullname").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  var queryString = "?name=" + username;
  queryString += "&email=" + email + "&fullname=" + fullname + "&password=" + password;
  console.log(queryString);
  ajaxRequest.open("GET","fetchdata.php" + queryString, true);
  ajaxRequest.send(null);

}
```

Comment: grazie mille, è che ho seguito più tutorial e provato a mischiare i codici dalle diverse guide! ultima domanda: se volessi fare in modo che si connettesse ad un database hostato su un dominio?

Comment: @utopy vale stesso , non cambia niente , il host ti da hostname , username , password e database per connetterti , è tutto uguale.  se il tuo problema si è risolto , metti come accettato la domanda

Comment: quindi devo solo mettere il file php sul server giusto? (scusa se ti massacro ahaha ma trovare un'italiano che aiuta su stackoverflow è tipo natale per me!)

Comment: devi caricare i tuoi file su tuo server , e poi devi creare database , e poi metti detagli giusti per : hostname , username , password , e cosi via , e basta

Comment: ci ho provato ( caricando il file php sul mio server e poi accedendoci linkandolo nel file script) ma quando completo il form nel mio file html su localhost ricevo questo errore:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load [...]. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:800' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Non puoi fare quello che stai provando a fare , i file php e database devono essere sul stesso server , non puoi fare quello che stai provando a fare ,

Comment: nono il file php è sullo stesso server del database, però la funzione in ajax  è su un file html in localhost! io vorrei fare un app in cordova dalla quale è possibile registrarsi e caricare le informazioni sul mio database!

Comment: @utopy ho aggiornato la risposta e cambiato una riga : new XMLHttpRequest({mozSystem: true}); , usa quello . il browser ti blocca perchè stavi facendo cross - domain access , che di default browser non ti permette di farlo , ma bisogna bypassarlo.

Comment: non funziona il tuo metodo, ho risolto aggiungendo
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST'); 
al file PHP solo che ora in mysql i campi all'interno del database sono vuoti invece di avere le informazioni del form

Comment: @utopy umm mi sa che non hai risolto, risolto sarebbe che sta mandando dati con successo , ma in questo caso no.

Comment: @utopy ti invito di chiudere questa domanda accetando la risposta , e creare una nuova domanda per il cross domain origin . che è una cosa diversa da questa domanda che hai postato.